# UserControl Listbox with a Generic ObservableCollection that can be Modified by Buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to be able to display lists of data in a ListBox with buttons that can move the items Up and Down and Remove items from the ListBoxes and reflect that in the data models.

SampleDesign: http://bigriverrubber.com/_uploads/sites/2/usercontrollistbox.jpg

I plan on having multiple ListBoxes just like this with the same functionality across several windows, so I thought I could make a UserControl with the ListBox and buttons I need inside it and have the buttons modify the data. That way I could just pass an ObservableCollection to the UserControl and I wouldn't have to recreate the buttons each time.

What I found out, however, is that I can't move the items if they are bound to an ObservableCollection, which they need to be for my purposes. From what I've read, I need to modify the collection instead.

But how do I do that from the UserControl? If the Type of the ObservableCollection needs to be variable so the ListBox can display many Types of lists, how can I possibly hope to target it to gain access to the Move and Remove methods in the ObservableCollection class?

I've tried taking the ItemsSource which was set to the ObservableCollection and converting it into an ObservableCollection< dynamic > but that didn't work.

I've tried Casting it as an ObservableCollection< T > and ObservableCollection< object > among others to no avail.

I've even tried restructuring my ViewModels under a GenericViewModel with a property of ObservableCollection< dynamic >, which failed and left my code in ruin so I had to return to a backup.

I've used an ItemsControl that changes the ListBox depending on which DataType it finds, but that would still mean I have to make separate button events anyway, so what's the point?

I would post some code, but seeing how nothing I've done has worked in the slightest I doubt that it will help any. At this point I don't even know if what I'm intending can be done at all.

If there are any suggestions on what code to post, feel free to ask.
EDIT: Here is a GenericViewModel. It doesn't work because I don't know what to set "Anything" to. EDIT: Added the UserControl

```cs
public class GenericViewModel : Observable
    {
        //-Fields

        private ObservableCollection<Anything> _items;
        private Anything _selectedItem;

        //-Properties

        public ObservableCollection<Anything> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { Set(ref _items, nameof(Items), value); }
        }
        public Anything SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { Set(ref _selectedItem, nameof(SelectedItem), value); }
        }

        //-Constructors

        public GenericViewModel()
        {
            if (Items == null) Items = new ObservableCollection<Anything>();
        }

        //-Logic

        public void MoveUp()
        {
            if (Items == null) return;
            Helper.MoveItemUp(Items, _items.IndexOf(_selectedItem));
        }
        public void MoveDown()
        {
            if (Items == null) return;
            Helper.MoveItemDown(Items, _items.IndexOf(_selectedItem));
        }
        public void Remove()
        {
            if (Items == null) return;
            Helper.RemoveItem(Items, _items.IndexOf(_selectedItem));
        }
    }
```

UserControl

```cs
 public partial class CustomListBox : UserControl
    {
        //-Fields

        //-Properties

        //-Dependencies

        //-Constructor

        public CustomListBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //-Methods

        private void ListboxButtonUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListboxButtonDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListboxButtonCopy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListboxButtonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BorderLayerThumbnail_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BorderLayerThumbnail_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="BRRG_Scrubber.User_Controls.CustomListBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BRRG_Scrubber"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="150">
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="10" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <!--ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Current}"-->
        <ListBox x:Name="listBoxPlus" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" >
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="14" />
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="14" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Document}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Variable}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Layer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.70*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="borderLayerThumbnail" BorderBrush="#FF707070" BorderThickness="1" Width="50" Height="50" MouseRightButtonDown="BorderLayerThumbnail_MouseRightButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="BorderLayerThumbnail_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/BRRG_Scrubber;component/Resources/Images/checkerboardtile.jpg" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Stretch="None" Viewport="0,0,12,12" TileMode="Tile"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" OpacityMask="Gray">
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visible}" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="12">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visible}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="12">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Locked}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <WrapPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                </Style>
            </WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Button x:Name="listboxButtonUp" Content="▲" Click="ListboxButtonUp_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="listboxButtonDown" Content="▼" Click="ListboxButtonDown_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="listboxButtonCopy" Content="⧉" Click="ListboxButtonCopy_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="listboxButtonDelete" Content="⛞" Click="ListboxButtonDelete_Click"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I would really like to be able to create a modified ListBox in a UserControl with buttons that can move items Up and Down and Remove them from the list which I can use for any ObservableCollection of any unknown Type. The ListBoxes I need would all function exactly the same except their Type would be unknown until runtime.

EDIT: New Code From Ed's Suggestions

MainViewModel

```cs
 public class MainViewModel : Observable
    {
        //-Fields

        private Project _project;

        private GenericViewModel<Document> _documentCollection;
        private GenericViewModel<Variable> _variableCollection;
        private GenericViewModel<Layer> _layerCollection;

        //-Properties

        public Project Project
        {
            get { return _project; }
            set { Set(ref _project, nameof(Project), value); }
        }

        public GenericViewModel<Document> DocumentCollection
        {
            get { return _documentCollection; }
            set { Set(ref _documentCollection, nameof(DocumentCollection), value); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LayerCollection)); }
        }

        public GenericViewModel<Variable> VariableCollection
        {
            get { return _variableCollection; }
            set { Set(ref _variableCollection, nameof(VariableCollection), value); }
        }

        public GenericViewModel<Layer> LayerCollection
        {
            get { return _layerCollection; }
            set { Set(ref _layerCollection, nameof(LayerCollection), value); }
        }        

        //-Constructors

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Project = new Project();

            DocumentCollection = new GenericViewModel<Document>();
            DocumentCollection.Items = Project.Documents;
        }

        //-Logic
    }
```

Test Window with Bindings

```xml
        <StackPanel>
            <uc:CustomListBox DataContext="{Binding DocumentCollection}" Height="100"/>
            <uc:CustomListBox DataContext="{Binding LayerCollection}" Height="200"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Project.Documents}" Height="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

GenericViewModel

```cs
public class GenericViewModel<Anything> : Observable, ICollectionViewModel
    {
        //-Fields

        private ObservableCollection<Anything> _items;
        private Anything _selectedItem;

        //-Properties

        public ObservableCollection<Anything> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { Set(ref _items, nameof(Items), value); }
        }
        public Anything SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { Set(ref _selectedItem, nameof(SelectedItem), value); }
        }

        //-Constructors

        public GenericViewModel()
        {
            if (Items == null) Items = new ObservableCollection<Anything>();
        }

        //-Logic
       ...Removed For Brevity...        
    }
```

Document Model Class

```cs
public class Document : Anything
    {
        //-Fields

        private string _filePath = "New Document";
        private ObservableCollection<Layer> _layers;
        private ObservableCollection<Selection> _selections;

        //-Properties

        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return _filePath; }
            set { Set(ref _filePath, nameof(FilePath), value); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Layer> Layers
        {
            get { return _layers; }
            set { Set(ref _layers, nameof(Layers), value); }
        }

        //-Constructors

        public Document()
        {
            if (Layers == null) Layers = new ObservableCollection<Layer>();
            if (Selections == null) Selections = new ObservableCollection<Selection>();
        }

        public Document(string filepath)
        {
            this.FilePath = filepath;

            if (Layers == null) Layers = new ObservableCollection<Layer>();
            if (Selections == null) Selections = new ObservableCollection<Selection>();

            Layers.Add(new Layer("LayerOne "+Name));
            Layers.Add(new Layer("LayerTwo " + Name));
            Layers.Add(new Layer("LayerThree " + Name));

            Selections.Add(new Selection());
            Selections.Add(new Selection());
        }

        //-Gets

        public string Name
        {
            get { return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Write a generic viewmodel which owns an ObservableCollection. It’s in charge of adding and removing items, via commands and methods. Bind a ListBoxes in your UserControl to the collection, bind buttons to commands. Your requirements are very vague, but you can do this with conventional data templating. ***Never*** use dynamic.

Comment: You may want to give your UserControl an ItemTemplate dependency property.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett "Write a generic viewmodel which owns an ObservableCollection." I thought I did that already, it didn't work because I don't/can't know what type the ObservableColleciton needs. If I can't use dynamic, then what do I use?

Comment: There are a million things you can do that have the string "ObservableColllection" somewhere in the code. Nine hundred and seventy-five thousand of those things are wrong. I have no idea which one of them you did. Can you show me what you did? Based on your extremely vague descriptions, it is impossible for me to guess what your code looks like, but it doesn't sound like you're doing MVVM.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Sorry, I added a GenericViewModel code block to the OP.

Comment: Your viewmodel isn't generic. What's `Anything`? What does your UserControl look like? Please don't make me ask multiple times for the same information. Before you post a question, you should have a [minimal, complete, and verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue you're having. I should have provided that link already.

Comment: I posted everything I could think to post. `Anything` doesn't have a reference and no class is built for it. It just symbolizes that I would like to make it interchangeable for any Type because I won't always know what Type I need. I'm going to rewrite it so it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It looks miles better than I anticipated.

Comment: This is a lot to take in. A lot of what you are saying is another language I'm only just familiar with. I'll try to put something together using what you've said. Thank you for sticking with me.

Comment: Let me know if you need clarification anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big issue here seems to be that you can't cast to a generic class with an unknown type parameter, but you want your viewmodel class to be properly generic. That circle is squareable in two different useful ways, both valuable to know, so we'll do both.

The proper MVVM way to do this is to give your viewmodel some command properties which call these methods. A DelegateCommand class is the same as a RelayCommand class; the internet is full of implementations if you don't have one already.

```
public ICommand MoveUpCommand { get; } = 
    new DelegateCommand(() => MoveUp());
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="▲" Command="{Binding MoveUpCommand}" />
```

Then get rid of those click event handlers. You don't need 'em. That very neatly solves your problem of calling those methods.

However, there's also a clean way to call those methods from code behind, and it's an important pattern to learn if you're going to be working with generics.

The classic solution to the casting problem is the one the framework uses for generic collections: Generic `IEnumerable<T>` implements non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable`. `List<T>` implements non-generic `System.Collections.IList`. Those non-generic interfaces provide the same operations, but in a non-generic way. You can always cast a `List<T>` to non-generic `IList` and call those methods and properties without knowing `T`.

Any well-designed collection can be assigned to a property of type `IEnumerable`: `ListBox.ItemsSource` is declared as `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, for example. Any collection can be assigned to it, without the ListBox needing to know what type is in the collection.

So let's write a non-generic interface that exposes the members we'll need to access without knowing any type parameters.

```
public interface ICollectionViewModel
{
    void MoveUp();
    void MoveDown();
    void Remove();
}
```

If one of those method prototypes included the collection item type, say `void RemoveItem(Anything x)`, that would complicate matters, but [there's a classic solution to that problem as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Your `Anything` is already used like a type parameter. All we need to do is declare it as one. Your methods already have the appropriate prototypes to implement the interface methods.

```
public class GenericViewModel<Anything> : Observable, ICollectionViewModel
```

Instantiate like so:

```
this.DocumentCollection = new GenericViewModel<Document>();
```

Now your codebehind can cast any instance of `GenericViewModel`, regardless of type parameter, to a non-generic interface that supports the needed operations:

```
private void ListboxButtonUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataContext is ICollectionViewModel icollvm)
    {
        icollvm.MoveUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is getting along very well, but I'm grappling with something right now. If I were to nest the Layers list inside of Documents, how would I be able to update a ListBox set to Layers when you select a new Document from its Listbox? So a Project has a collection of Documents. Each Document has a collection of Layers. If I had Document1 selected in a ListBox how could I change the Layers ListBox to show Document1's Layers? I'll post my current code in the OP in a moment.

Comment: Ok, I have some of my new code added to the OP. I think I know how to change the bindings in codebehind, but I don't know how to modify this to allow nesting the GenericViewModels using MVVM and bindings.

Comment: You don't need to change a binding in codebehind. What do you want to put in that ListBox? I don't understand. You already assigned `Project.Documents` to `DocumentCollection.Items`, and `DocumentCollection.Items` is being displayed in the first instance of `uc:CustomListBox`. Are you talking about the `Layer` collection still?

Comment: You'd use `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentCollection.SelectedItem.Layers}" />`, if you want to list the `Layers` collection from the selected document.

Comment: I would also like to show that `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentCollection.SelectedItem.Layers}" />` inside another one of these CustomListBoxes, so it would have buttons to move and delete as well. I'm wanting to put the Layers inside each Document and populate the same ListBox with buttons with the currently selected Document's Layer Collection.

Comment: @DanielSchrecker I'd change the type of Document.Layers to `GenericViewModel<Layer>`, then have `<uc:CustomListBox DataContext="{Binding DocumentCollection.SelectedItem.Layers}" />`. Incidentally, if you want to use any other bindings on those usercontrols, that won't be possible, because we're explicitly setting DataContext. But that's not an issue right at the moment.

Comment: That did it, I didn't know it is acceptable to put ViewModels inside Models, so it didn't occur to me. Thank you so much for the help. I'm marking as answered, but I might have some more questions in the future.

Comment: Acceptable! It's mandatory! Viewmodels within viewmodels within viewmodels within viewmodels -- that's what it's all about! By all means, hit me up again if necessary.